# bind datagridview with list in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am binding a datagridview with List<> . The problem is that this is not displaying the value correctly. The problem is that when i bind the value to datagridview i can show list first value correctly but not inside of list . I can see `_activity.Date` . But i can't see the value properly `_activity.ActivityLocation.Address.City` .

```
foreach(Activity _activity in _pck.Activity)
              {

             txtActivity.Text = _activity.Date;
             txtActivityTime.Text = _activity.Time;
             txtActivityLocationDesc.Text = _activity.ActivityLocation.Description;
             txtSignedForByName.Text = _activity.ActivityLocation.SignedForByName;
             txtCity.Text = _activity.ActivityLocation.Address.City;
             txtAddressCountry.Text = _activity.ActivityLocation.Address.CountryCode;
             txtPacelStatus.Text = _activity.Status.StatusCode.Code;
             txtParcelStatusDesc.Text = _activity.Status.StatusType.Description;
             txtStatus.Text = _activity.Status.StatusCode.Code;

             }
```

for check the value i bind the value to textbox i can see only list record . So here i want that i bind the value to datagridview. Below is the value that is displaying in the datagridview. Below is the image the datagridview. Can you please tell me what i need to do and how i will do this, thanks for your comment.
[image]

Comment: How do you bind the List of Activity class in DataGridView?

Comment: Without seeing the code for the List and the class(es) it contains we can't tell for sure.  But at least 3 of the DGV's fields don't show the __values__ but the object __types__. This means that the fields are __either__ not of type text/string, __or__ not of the type the DGV cells expect __or__ don't have a `ToString(`) method.. So you should either change that or use `ToString()` in your assignments.